# Use async instead of multiple await (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, api, async-await

I have the below API call. getA, getB and getC are the API calls being made. Since i use await, these are sequential calls.

How do i make it asynchronous and return the result only when all the calls are completed.

```
handler: async function (request, h) {
                const headers = { headers: { “x-userId”: “sdsds” } };
                const getA = ( await getData("app/getA”)) || options.headers.STORES;
                const getB = ( await getData("app/getB”)) || [];
                const getC = ( await postData("app/getC”, { payload: {} }, headers)) || [];
                const result = {
                    status: "OK",
                    payload: {
                        stores: getA,
                        markets: getB,
                        groups: getC
                    }
                };
                return h.response(result);
            }
```

Comment: Looks like that is how it is already coded, you await the return of `getData` and `postData` calls. What is your actual result versus expected result?

Comment: @DrewReese- agree. these await the return of getData and postData. but arent they executing sequentially when we use await with it ? I wanted to make it asynchronous so that getB doesnot have to wait for getA to complete, and getC doesnot have to wait for getA and getB to complete. and the result should be passed only when all the 3 calls arre completed

Comment: Ah, I see, I misread what you were trying/asking to do. You want to fire off all three requests *concurrently* and only return a result when they've all completed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you're looking for or not...

IMO using async/await is a good way to do this because you need to ensure the payload has that data but I could be wrong.

```
handler: function (request, h) {
    const headers = { headers: { 'x-userId': 'sdsds' } };
    const payload = {};

    getData('app/getA').then(data => {
        payload.stores = data;
    });

    getData('app/getB').then(data => {
        payload.markets = data;
    });

    getData('app/getC').then(data => {
        payload.groups = data;
    });

    const result = {
        status: "OK",
        payload,
    };
    return h.response(result);
}
```

Comment: @mmason33- i see you are making it asynchronous. but how would result variable know that all the 3 calls made prior are completed. ?

Comment: Thats the thing it wouldn't. These async blocks would finish when they finish but that's what the user asked for.

Comment: @mmason33- sorry if i wasnt clear. i agree that your code would let the async blocks finish when they can. but if the const result need to get the payload. whereas in your case, the result might execute before the AP call is complete. Am i right >?

Comment: Yes you are correct. To avoid this behavior use async/await.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do a [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) of the three values you need. Promise.all takes an array of promises and returns an array of resolved responses. They can resolve in any order but the overall promise doesn't resolve until *all* promises have resolved.

```
handler: async function (request, h) {
  const headers = { headers: { “x-userId”: “sdsds” } };

  const requests = [
    getData("app/getA”),
    getData("app/getB”),
    postData("app/getC”, { payload: {} }, headers))
  ];

  const [getA, getB, getC] = await Promise.all(requests);

  const result = {
    status: "OK",
    payload: {
      stores: getA || options.headers.STORES,
      markets: getB || [],
      groups: getC || [],
    }
  };

  return h.response(result);
}
```

Note: With Promise.all, if any single promise rejects, then the entire Promise.all rejects. [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) resolves when all promises have either fulfilled or rejected.